# Using tab causes math in between `\[ \]` to move back two spaces instead of being align

Tags: auctex, latex, indentation, emacsclient

- Operating system: Ubuntu 14.04
- Emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2015-03-12 onlcy01-03
- AUCTeX version: AUCTeX-version is a variable defined in `tex-site.el'.
  Its value is "2015-03-08"

---

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

The tab button cause the first line after `\[` to -2 indent and then `\]` to do another -2 indent. It was causing this behavior with the `cases` environment as well, but I was able to stop it by adding `("cases" LaTeX-indent-tabular)` to `'(LaTeX-indent-environment-list`. I tried adding `("displaymath" current-indentation)` but this didn't solve the problem.

```
;; Start server and set directory
(setq server-socket-dir (format "/tmp/emacs1000"))
;; Not sure if (useruid) does anything or the difference between
;; (server-start) and '(server-mode t) in custom
;(setq server-socket-dir (format "/tmp/emacs1000" (user-uid)))
;(server-start)

;; Package initialize
(package-initialize)

;; Package list M-x package-list-packages
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("marmelade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/"))

;; AucTex & RefTeX
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTex t)
(global-font-lock-mode t)
(setq font-lock-maximum-decoration t)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(setq TeX-save-query nil)

;; Copy and paste between Emac   instances     
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)

;; Disablin autosave                                                           
(setq auto-save-default nil)

;; Adjusting tab distance
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)

;; Enable Line Numbering
(setq line-number-mode t)
(setq column-number-mode t)

;; Set the fill column
(setq default-fill-column 80)

;; Turn on Auto Fill mode automatically in all modes
;; Auto-fill-mode the the automatic wrapping of lines and insertion of
;; newlines when the cursor goes over the column limit.
;; This should actually turn on auto-fill-mode by default in all major
;; modes. The other way to do this is to turn on the fill for specific modes
;; via hooks.  
(setq auto-fill-mode 1)

;;  Turn on visual line mode
(global-visual-line-mode t)

;; Prevent Emacs from making backup files
(setq make-backup-files nil)

;; Cleverref setup
(eval-after-load
    "latex"
  '(TeX-add-style-hook
    "cleveref"
    (lambda ()
      (if (boundp 'reftex-ref-style-alist)
      (add-to-list
       'reftex-ref-style-alist
       '("Cleveref" "cleveref"
         (("\\cref" ?c) ("\\Cref" ?C) ("\\cpageref" ?d) ("\\Cpageref" ?D)))))
      (add-to-list 'reftex-ref-style-default-list "Cleveref")
      (TeX-add-symbols
       '("cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)))))

;; Latexmk setup
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
         (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %s" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file))
  (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
      (TeX-next-error t)
    (progn
      (demolish-tex-help)
      (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 
      (lambda ()
        (push 
         '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
           :help "Run Latexmk on file")
         TeX-command-list)))

;; Set okular to open with C-c C-v view option 
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("Okular" "okular --unique %u")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular")))

;; Paren checking
(load "paren")
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)

;; Adaptive wrap
;(require 'adaptive-wrap)

(when (fboundp 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
  (defun my-activate-adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode ()
    "Toggle `visual-line-mode' and `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode' simultaneously."
    (if visual-line-mode
        (adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode 1)
      (adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode -1)))
  (add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook 'my-activate-adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(LaTeX-indent-environment-list
   (quote
    (("verbatim" current-indentation)
     ("verbatim*" current-indentation)
     ("tabular" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
     ("tabular*" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
     ("align" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
     ("align*" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
     ("array" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
     ("eqnarray" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
     ("eqnarray*" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
     ("displaymath" current-indentation)
     ("equation")
     ("equation*")
     ("picture")
     ("tabbing")
     ("table")
     ("table*")
     ("cases" LaTeX-indent-tabular))))
 '(TeX-PDF-mode t)
 '(TeX-newline-function (quote newline-and-indent))
 '(TeX-show-compilation t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" "okular -unique %o#src:%n%b"))))
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((output-pdf "Okular"))))
 '(compilation-auto-jump-to-first-error t)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(ispell-lazy-highlight nil)
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (rainbow-delimiters adaptive-wrap auto-indent-mode)))
 '(server-mode t))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Additionally, `synctex` has stopped working as well. I have in my `~\.latexmkrc`

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -synctex=1' %O %S;
```

so I am not quite sure with what has cause `synctex` to stop working. All these problems started to occur when I setup emacs, AUCTeX, and Latexmk on a different laptop. I used the same configuration settings but they only work properly on the other computer.

Comment: It's the effect of a recent addition to AUCTeX, this has also been reported here https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20227  I'll have a look in the following days.

Comment: @giordano okay so it wasn't just me. Thanks. I am glad to see you answer questions here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with indentation of `\[...\]` should have been fixed with this commit: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=c2f6e9c4ad208ebddadd42a0314a59503399d00f  You can apply the patch locally or wait for the AUCTeX package in GNU Elpa to be updated.

Comment: So a simple git clone/pull should do it then?

Comment: If you use AUCTeX git version yes of course, I thought you used the Elpa package but perhaps I'm wrong ;-)

Comment: I use git. I just applied it. I will restart emacs and see what happens.

Comment: It worked. Do you have any insight on my question about synctex?

Comment: Not for the time being, sorry, but I suggest you to ask as a separate question.